# Controlling InAppBrowser elements

Tags: hybrid, inappbrowser

I working with my developer son (beginner and not experienced) to develop a Hybrid App for iOS and Android using PhoneGap. 
The problem we are facing is when we show some particular content / pages in InAppBrowser. The iOS has navigation bar at the bottom and the Android at the top of the page. We want a consistant experience, hence want the navigation control at the top for both versions.

I spoke to some of experienced people regarding this and they tell me that we cant change the properties of the InAppBrowser elements. Example, we can completely hide/show the navigation bar but we can't position it on top for iOS and can't change the text as well such as label of the navigation from DONE to Back.

Is there a solution to achieve this. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to change it you will need to change the plugin. The current version seem to be here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Just fork it and use it to build your app. You will need have a Mac computer to build for iOS though. You will find instructions on building applications on your computer on PhoneGap page (see also instructions for [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser), but note that you would have to pass an URL to plugin add command).

Note however that consistent experience on all systems is not really possible. For example Android already has a back button so it is not crucial to have it for users on Android. Experience in many cases should be consistent through all applications on the same system, not within a single application.